# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'listBox1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am getting the above error. The error is on line 33, it says.

Here's the code:

Source Error:

```
Line 31: 
Line 32: while(r.Read()) {
Line 33:     listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(r["first_name"], r["first_name"])); //this is the offending line
Line 34: }
Line 35: con.Close();
```

Now, I figured my ASP.NET was fine, I have the following code there:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBox1" runat="server">
</asp:ListBox>
```

What might I be doing incorrectly here? I have the user control setup in the .aspx file, I have the correct item in my .aspx.cs file - it should work, shouldn't it? What am I missing? I'm still new to C#

Comment: That mean that you are calling you listbox when it is not available (IE is in a different context). Have you added this listbox in a try/catch block? It is hard to answer this w/ out seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: It is not inside a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a `UserControl` instance inside your aspx then you have to find the `ListBox` control inside the `UserControl` instance using its `Controls` collection.

[Here's a link on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls.aspx)

Another alternative is to have your individual control handlers inside the code-behind file of the `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your listBox1 control exist inside your designer.cs file? If not, regenerate the auto-generated C# file by deleting it, right clicking the aspx file and clicking on "Convert to Web Application".